# Sending large files to the server

Tags: c#, sockets, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to send large files to Asp.net server from my Xamarin Android application. I found the best way to do it would be to send the file in chunks rather than sending it whole. I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.techcoil.com/blog/uploading-large-http-multipart-request-with-system-net-httpwebrequest-in-c/) which usesHttpWebRequest to send the request to the server. In the following lines of code in the tutorial, the file is sent in chunks to the server:

```
/ Send the file binaries over to the server, in 1024 bytes chunk
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileUrl, FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
    s.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
} // end while
fileStream.Close();
```

I know that `s.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)` writes the byte on the network socket but how does the back and forth communication work? Does the client wait for the server to respond and send the next chunk to the server or all chunks are written on the network stream and sent together?
Right now the server code I have receives the request which is the full file rather than it's chunks. My server side code looks like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile()
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                // NOTE: To store in memory use postedFile.InputStream
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

How can I make sure that the connection doesn't time out while the file is sending and is this the most efficient way of sending large file to the server? How can I resume the upload if their a blimp in the netowrk connection on the client side?

Comment: I have an issue with the link you posted.  It is old from 2012.  I have not been able to use http 1.1 with latest version of httpRequest.  http 1.1 sends chunks and I have not been able to get more than one chunk.  The request returns 100 Continue (not 200 Done) and cannot get any more chunk.  I've been telling people to use http 1.0 using following :             HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your response. I receive the file on the server through the request. If the file is sent in chunks, why isn't it received in chunks also on the server?

Comment: Okay so if I use Http 1.0 instead of 1.1, then the server will receive the file in chunks? I'll test it

Comment: It will be a stream.  The http uses TCP as transport network level.  Tcp only allows max size of ~1500 bytes.  The http automatically combines the tcp.  The http can be in pieces and the pieces are combined into a stream by the net library.